# Efficient algorithm for getting from 1 to n with 3 specific operations

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, number-theory

**The question:**

> Given those 3 valid operations over numbers and an integer n:
>
> - add 1 to the number
> - multiply the number by 2
> - multiply the number by 3
>
> describe an efficient algorithm for the minimal number of operations of getting from 1 to n with the 3 operations mentioned above.
>
> For example for n = 28 the answer is 4 : 1 * 3 * 3 * 3 + 1 = 27 + 1 = 28.

I wrote the code below in java and it takes a lot of time to end for num>=1000. Can you help me understand what is wrong w.r.t. efficiency. I am trying to make a more efficient algorithm to solve the problem. Please help.

```
public static int ToN(int num){
    return to(1,num);
}
public static int to(int x,int y){
    if (x==y)
        return 0;
    if (x>y)
        return y;
    return Math.min(Math.min(to(x+1,y),to(x*2,y)),to(x*3,y))+1;
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about the naive recursive Fibonacci implementation and why that's slow? Your code is slow for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Dynamic Programming

Using previously computed results to compute new results. This makes the solution linear, as opposed to exponential in your case.

**Python program**

```
import sys
n = int(raw_input())
dp = [sys.maxint]*(n+1)
dp[1] = 1

for i in xrange(2, n+1):
    dp[i] = dp[i-1]+1
    if i%2==0:    dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i/2]+1)
    if i%3==0:    dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i/3]+1)

print dp[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is slow, because you're not caching previously calculated results (best solutions for i < num), and you recalculating them each time. This make it working for exponential time, because each call of toN function spawns 3 other calls, and so on recursivelly

```
public static int ToN(int num){
    int[] opsRequired = new int[num+1];
    opsRequired[1] = 1;
    for (int i=2; i <= num; i++) {
         opsRequired[i] = opsRequired[i-1];
         if (i % 2 == 0)
             opsRequired[i] = Math.min(opsRequired[i], opsRequired[i/2]);
         if (i % 3 == 0)
             opsRequired[i] = Math.min(opsRequired[i], opsRequired[i/3]);
         opsRequired[i]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things that you can introspect:
1) Why does your recursive method need two parameters? If the problem involves moving from 1 to n at all times, we can manage with just a single parameter. Note that while recursing, you pass *y* as is (and you don't operate on *y*'s value inside your method either). This usually indicates that the parameter itself is redundant.
2) After having optimized the parameters, we can now [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the solution. This would speed up your method greatly.

Answer (score 0):

For positive integers, multiplying by 3 will always be faster than by 2, which will always be faster than adding 1.   So the algorithm is trivial.

```
if x == y return 0
if x <= y/3 return 1 + to(x*3,y)
if x <= y/2 return 1 + to(x*2,y)
return y-x
```